# JButton adding properties

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Is there a way to get the propery value we declared this way?

```
JButton button = new javax.swing.JButton(){
    public int value=0;
}

button.addActionListener(listener);
//in action listener
public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

JButton btn = (JButton)evt.getSource();
btn.value =2; //error
}
```

Comment: actionPerformed is lowercase, mandatory. Indentation would be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access properties / methods of annonymous class outside of the instance itself.

The reason is that the compiler knows that `btn` is a JButton, not your extension, and you can't cast to this extension, as it doesn't have a name.

You need to create an internal class or class in a separate file and instantiate it, for example:

```
static class MyButton extends JButton {
    public int value=0;
}

// ....
MyButton btn = new MyButton();
btn.addActionListener(listener);
// ....

@Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    MyButton btn = (MyButton)evt.getSource();
    btn.value = 2; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Im quite new in this and I have never seen static class that extends another Class. What does it change in this case?

Comment: The use of the keyword static is done if this is an internal class, to avoid creating the class itself for every instance. The major change is that we now have a name for this kind of a class, which we didn't use to have, so we can refer to it's properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Component.setName() to save at least a string with your Component.